# UI MVC Grid with custom command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a grid which displays a list of branches. I also have a ContactDetails button on each row which is a custom command popping a Kendo window displaying the details. It all works fine. However, I want these details to be editable. How should I approach this? I cannot seem to be able to access the model through the window.

I am using the code from their custom command demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command

Ultimately, what I want is the grid to pass in the model representing the relevant row into the window so that the model can be modified and then persisted on the database.

Comment: What error are you getting? What does your code look like?

Comment: I am not getting an error. It displays everything fine. I don't know how to bind the data input from the user with the model so that changes can be persisted onto the database.

My code is a copy of the link provided. The bits with "#= #" ("#= Firstname #") display all the data I need but I don't understand how they work and how to make them editable.

Comment: Why not use the inbuilt editing features of the grid? e.g. using the edit command. This then uses from my understanding the MVVM binding from the datasource to the editor controls/ editor window.

Comment: I am using the edit command to edit data in a single row of the grid. The purpose of the window is to display additional data which can also be edited. I am using the window to keep the grid narrower as there are quite a few columns already.